# Ajax.Beginform doesnt update target div

Tags: c#, html, ajax, model-view-controller, ajax.beginform

Im using Ajax.Beginform() instead of Html.BeginForm(), because i want to show result of submit in partial view.

But when i click submitbutton, the div doesnt update. Instead it shows like a ordinary view without the rest of the site.

My code looks like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchParticipant", "Search", 
new { @role = "form", @class = "col-lg-12" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultViewParticipant" }))
            {
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search</a>
}

<div id="resultViewParticipant">
</div>
```

In the controller the ActionResult looks like this:

```
public ActionResult SearchParticipant(SearchReturnModel model)
    {
        var result = searchManager.SearchResultParticipant(model.Participant, RegionId);
        return PartialView("_ResultParticipant", result);
    }
```

Ajax works flawlessly elsewhere on the website, so unobtrusive is properly implemented.

I would appreciate if I do not have to go through javascript in this case

Comment: Could it be because you are using an <a href ..> instead of a <input type="submit" ...> ?

Comment: I want to use <a> because then i can use <span> before the text on the button. I doesnt know how to include <span> inside input value.

Comment: I solved it with <button type="submit"> instead of <input type="submit">. Thanks.